# Different File upload with list

Tags: file-upload

I have a list that has 10 to 15 columns. From those columns, I have two places where two attachment section is there. One is single attachment and the other is multiple attachment.

E.g.:

Name: [Name input field]
Address:[Address Input field] 
Resume: [Attachment]---This is the first attachment(single of course) 
Gender: [input choice] 
Status: [input choice] 
Supporting Docs: [Attachment]---This is the second place (multiple attachment)

What I need to consider:
1. I must not use list's default attachment option.
2. I must not use Visual Studio, full thing is client side.
3. Every attachment option must have delete option (remove link).
4. The column option must come the order I mentioned.
5. No popup is allowed!
6. InfoPath is extremely prohibited!

If I think, the List is parent the attachment/document are children, I can link them up. But problem is when I do attach, the attachment is saved to the document library, but I didn't get the ID of the parent list which is not saved yet! My link up fails.

Can anybody suggest me what can I do.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't completely understand what you're trying to do.

But generally speaking, I dislike attachments and urge people to use lookup fields instead. The problem with attachments is that they are not retrievable through search, contents aren't indexed, do not get any decent SharePoint document management features whatsoever (Versioning, recycle bin, etc).

When using "attachments" I usually advise my customers with two options:

1. Use document sets instead, you can create a document set where you can setup the metadata. Afterwards you can simply drag drop your files into the document set and they will be "attached" to your metadata.
2. Use lookup fields, create a seperate document library where documents are stored, use the lookup field to point to any documents you want to be attached to your list item.

Comment: Hi Christoffel, thanks for your advice. Actually I'm doing custom development and client side based. I have seen lot of attachment option in the air but my requirement doesn't meet them. In one place I have to have single attachment and in other place I have to have multiple attachment  facilities in a list. I am looking for option the way I can achieve the attachment thing.